# forcing numbers to 2 digits for a calculation

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple JS function that calculates social security benefits based on a number (called average monthly income). I'm struggling with where and how to force the number to no more than 2 digits. I also haven't figured out form validation but that's for another time. My question: where and how to make the output (my y variable) a number no longer than 2 digits? Thank you in advance.

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="ami" placeholder="enter your AMI"><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="calculateButton" onclick="ssCalculator()" value="Calculate">
</form>

<p id="results">
</p>

<script>
    function ssCalculator() {
        var pia90 = 926; //updated for 2019
        var pia32 = 5583; //updated for 2019
        var pia15 = 5583.01; //updated for 2019
        var x = document.getElementById("ami").value;
        if (x<pia90) {
            let y = (.9*x);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 62</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*.7) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 67</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 70</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*1.24) +".");
        }
        if (pia90<x && x<pia32) {
            let y = (.9*pia90)+.32*(x-pia90);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 62</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*.7) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 67</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 70</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*1.24) +".");
        }
        if (x>pia15) {
            let y = (.9*pia90)+(.32*pia32)+.15*(x-pia15);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 62</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*.7) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 67</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 70</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*1.24) +".");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `toFixed()` method.

Example:

```
let y = (.9*x).toFixed(2)
```

Additional usage information:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Y.toFixed(0);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. While your answer might be correct, you need to add some explanation so that it's more useful to the user

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `toFixed()` function for more [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id="ami" placeholder="enter your AMI"><br><br>
        <input type="button" name="calculateButton" onclick="ssCalculator()" value="Calculate">
    </form>

<p id="results">
</p>

<script>
    function ssCalculator() {
        var pia90 = 926; //updated for 2019
        var pia32 = 5583; //updated for 2019
        var pia15 = 5583.01; //updated for 2019
        var x = document.getElementById("ami").value;
        if (x<pia90) {
            let y = (.9*x);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 62</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*.7).toFixed(2) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 67</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y).toFixed(2) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 70</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*1.24).toFixed(2) +".");
        }
        if (pia90<x && x<pia32) {
            let y = (.9*pia90)+.32*(x-pia90);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 62</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*.7).toFixed(2) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 67</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y).toFixed(2) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 70</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*1.24).toFixed(2) +".");
        }
        if (x>pia15) {
            let y = (.9*pia90)+(.32*pia32)+.15*(x-pia15);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 62</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*.7).toFixed(2) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 67</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y).toFixed(2) +".<br>");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += ("If you start receiving Social Security at <strong>age 70</strong> your monthly benefit would be $" + (y*1.24).toFixed(2) +".");
        }
    }
</script>
```

For some basic form validation just change the `type` in `input` to `number` which will only accept numbers